# Nginx timeout on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have a Ruby on Rails application running on DigitalOcean. I keep running into a 504 Gateway Timeout error with Nginx. Most recently it happened when running `service unicorn restart` and `service nginx restart`. I don't see anything apparent in the production logs about any problems with nginx or unicorn. In fact it is saying that my root view was rendered, despite me getting a time out error. I'm a bit confused about what might be causing this error and I'm not a little unsure what information I can provide in this question to be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your unicorn config at `/home/unicorn/unicorn.conf`
and comment out the line `user 'rails'`

then:

`service unicorn restart`